# How can I write a CMake project configuration for a project with interface and implementation separation for selection from multiple implementations?

Tags: c, cmake

Assuming the following folder structure:

```
│   CMakeLists.txt
│   main.c
│
├───implementation
│   │   CMakeLists.txt
│   │
│   ├───A
│   │       CMakeLists.txt
│   │       one.c
│   │       two.c
│   │
│   └───B
│           CMakeLists.txt
│           one.c
│           two.c
│
└───interface
        CMakeLists.txt
        one.h
        two.h
```

- Header files in interface folder contain only function declarations.
- C files in implementation folders contain implementations of those functions. They should be able to include header files from the interface folder.
- main.c also includes header files from the interface folder and contains code using interface functions.
- Root CMakeLists.txt selects one of the implementations (A or B) based on some compile time parameter.
- Everything is statically linked.

The question is, what is the most canonical way in CMake to achieve the above? Should, for example, the interface folder content be added as an [INTERFACE library](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-buildsystem.7.html#interface-libraries)? Based on the documentation a primary use-case for INTERFACE libraries is header-only libraries, which is not the case for the content of header files in the interface folder.

The folder structure is just an example, so feel free to suggest a different one. The main requirement is to keep the interface, the implementation and the root project separated. They could be separate Git repositories for example.

The content of interface and implementation folders should be reusable without modifications (including CMakeLists.txt) from different root projects.

Comment: "_Everything is statically linked._" use the `STATIC` argument to [`add_library`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/add_library.html), or [`BUILD_SHARED_LIBS`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/variable/BUILD_SHARED_LIBS.html) (which is assumed false if not specified)

Comment: `a primary use-case for INTERFACE libraries is header-only libraries, which is not the case for the content of header files` sooo why is it not the case?? `most canonical` is opinion based. That's just a completely normal folder structure, write it as a normal Cmake structure, there is nothing "canonical" in having two libraries implementing same functions. I do no understand what "canonical" are you searching for.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming only one implementation will be used, and that your project consists of a single executable, given your file/directory layout, you could do it something like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION #[[something >= 3.1]])
project(hello_world)

add_executable(hello_world_main main.c)

target_include_directories(hello_world_main PUBLIC interface)

# if you want to set a fallback value of HELLO_WORLD_IMPLEMENTATION, do it here, like
if(NOT DEFINED HELLO_WORLD_IMPLEMENTATION)
  set(HELLO_WORLD_IMPLEMENTATION A) # or B. your choice.
endif()

set(target_name_for_implementation hello_world_main)
if("${HELLO_WORLD_IMPLEMENTATION}" STREQUAL "A")
  add_subdirectory(implementation/A)
elseif("${HELLO_WORLD_IMPLEMENTATION}" STREQUAL "B")
  add_subdirectory(implementation/B)
else()
  # you don't need this if you set a fallback value of HELLO_WORLD_IMPLEMENTATION
  message(FATAL_ERROR "HELLO_WORLD_IMPLEMENTATION needs to be \"A\" or \"B\"")
endif()
unset(target_name_for_implementation)
```

In implementation/A/CMakeLists.txt or implementation/B/CMakeLists.txt:

```
target_sources("${target_name_for_implementation}" PRIVATE one.c two.c)
```

Adjust as needed.

The user building the library would set `HELLO_WORLD_IMPLEMENTATION` to a value of their choice. They could do it on the commandline with [`-D`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake.1.html#cmdoption-cmake-D), or if using your project as a subdirectory added by `add_subdirectory` or `FetchContent`, by using [`set()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/set.html), or if using CMake presets, by using the `cacheVariables` field of a [configure preset](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/manual/cmake-presets.7.html#configure-preset).

Comment: I can't have name of the executable (hello_world_main) in CMakeLists.txt of implementation. Implementation should be reusable from different executables. What about CMakeLists.txt in the interface folder? Are you suggesting it is not needed at all?

Comment: @user930473 "_Are you suggesting it is not needed at all?_" yes. It is not necessarily needed. feel free to add it if you have reason to do so.

Comment: @user930473 "_I can't have name of the executable (hello_world_main) in CMakeLists.txt of implementation. Implementation should be reusable from different executables_" see edit.

Comment: That is probably the most minimalist way but is it the most canonical one? Wouldn't it be more correct to have add_library() in the implementation and the interface CMakeLists.txt files and target_link_libraries() calls in the root CMakeLists.txt? If so, then should add_library(<name> INTERFACE) be used in the interface/CMakeLists.txt?

Comment: @user930473 what you do with respect to whether you want to separate this stuff into its own library has **nothing specifically to do with CMake** and everything to do with the way you want to structure your project. It is not a matter of correctness. If either works, then either works, and the choice of what you do is up to you. You did not specify what kind of choice you wanted, and your question made no mention of libraries besides use of interface libraries, which doesn't make sense because you have _implementations_. So I assumed that you didn't want a library.

Comment: Discussion here on what is "canonical" with respect to CMake here is irrelevant. Choose how you want to structure your project, and then ask how to do it in CMake.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I write a CMake project configuration for a project with interface and implementation separation for selection from multiple implementations?

As any CMake project configuration, write an option.

```
option(USE_IMPLEMENTATION "Use A or B")
target_link_libraries(main ${USE_IMPLEMENTATION})
```

> what is the most canonical way in CMake to achieve the above?

Two libraries A and B from respective folders, one interface library in the interface folder, and a main executable in the main folder that links with A or B.

> Should, for example, the interface folder content be added as an INTERFACE library?

Yes.

Comment: How to make interface header files includable in implementation source files? I was not able to achieve this with add_subdirectory and target_link_libraries in implementation CMakeLists.txt (see my answer).

Comment: `target_link_libraries(A PUBLIC Interface)`

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution I came up with:

Root CMakeLists.txt

```
project(Test C)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME})

target_sources(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE
    main.c
)

add_subdirectory("interface")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE 
    Interface
)

add_subdirectory("implementation/${IMPL_NAME}")
target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME} PRIVATE 
    ${IMPL_NAME}
)
```

interface/CMakeLists.txt

```
add_library(Interface INTERFACE)

target_include_directories(Interface INTERFACE .)
```

implementation/A/CMakeLists.txt (B is the same, only "A" replaced with "B")

```
add_library(A)

target_sources(A PRIVATE
    one.c 
    two.c 
)

target_link_libraries(A PRIVATE Interface)
```